# Expansion of box in tabularx

Tags: tabularx

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal lines
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering and \RaggedRight macros
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\usepackage{siunitx} %  comprehensive (SI) units package



\begin{document}



\begin{table}[ht]
\small % is it necessary?
\newlength\colwidth 
\settowidth\colwidth{plates (USP)} % set width of 1st col.

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{\colwidth} *{6}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
    Key figures
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Toluene} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Nicotinamide}\\

    \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} 
    & 1st run  & 2nd run  & $\overline{x}~\pm~c_{\overline{x}}$ 
    & 1st run  & 2nd run & $\overline{x}~\pm~c_{\overline{x}}$\\

    \midrule
Capacity factor
    & $\num{1.78e-3}$ & $\num{5.35e-3}$ & $\num{3e-3} \pm \num{2.3e-2}$ & $\num{7.08e-1}$ & $\num{7.01e-1}$ & $\num{7.0e-1} \pm \num{4e-2}$ \\
    \bottomrule
    [0.5mm]
     \multicolumn{7}{l}{\small 1st run: 28.09.2020; 2nd run: 01.10.2020;  $\overline{x}$: average;  $c_{\overline{x}}$: $95\%$ confidence interval }
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Computed Descriptors}
    \label{tab:descriptors}
\end{table}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, use `\multicolumn{2}{c,l or r}{Toluene}`.

Comment: avoid scaling tables, in general it  just makes inconsistent font sizes, but here `\scalebox{1}{` does nothing other than force white space before the table (and an overfull box). Setting `\leftskip` inside `\scalebox` does nothing at all.

Comment: could you give me an example how to do it avoiding scalebox?

Comment: I edited the code using what @Bernard told me using \multicolumn. Can I center THe wird Toluene in the middle of the box? Is there a tool to also expand the box of Key figures in the vertical?

Comment: What  do you mean exactly with you second question? All cells in the first row should be vertically centred?

Comment: Regarding your recent edit: What else will be shown in your table? Will the other rows contain numbers in the same order of magnitude? How wide will the other entries be? Do columns 2 to 7 have to be equally wide although the widths of their contents differ quite significantly?

Comment: Probably you could redesign your table as follows in order to save quite some space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v8EU.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would reorganize several aspects of the `tabularx` material. They are, in no particular order:

- Give the table a more open and inviting "look" by omitting all vertical lines and by using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.
- Center the material in the 6 data columns
- Permit hyphenation in the first column, even in the first word of each cell
- Center the cell contents *vertically* via a suitable redefinition of `\tabularxcolumn`
- Drop the **bolding** -- unless you want to be perceived as liking to **shout** at your readers... -- and, instead, provide more visual structure in the header part of the table with the use of judiciously-placed `\cmidrule` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal lines
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering and \RaggedRight macros
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small % is it necessary?
\newlength\colwidth 
\settowidth\colwidth{plates (USP)} % set width of 1st col.

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{\colwidth} *{6}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
    Key figures
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Toluene} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Nicotinamide}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Adenine} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
    & 1st run 28.09.2020 & 2nd run 01.10.2020 
    & 1st run 28.09.2020 & 2nd run 01.10.2020 
    & 1st run 28.09.2020 & 2nd run 01.10.2020 \\
    \midrule
    Retention time & 1&2&3&4&5&6\\
    Peak area  & 1&2&3&4&5&6\\
    Theoretical plates (USP) & 1&2&3&4&5&6\\
    Asymmetry & 1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 
    Resolution & 1&2&3&4&5&6\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Computed Descriptors}
    \label{tab:descriptors}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, it seems that i didn't understood OP question well ...

Comment: thank you very much. I tried to applay your corrections. Does it look good to you know?

Comment: @Elia - You're most welcome. Since you asked for my opinions ... I'd like to suggest that you (a) load `siunitx` with the option `tight-spacing`, (b) use "Key figures" as the argument of `\settowidth\colwidth`, (c) change the second instance of `\multicolumn{3}{c}` to `\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}`, (d) change `\cmidrule(lr){5-7}` to `\cmidrule(l){5-7}`, (e) replace all instances of `\overline` with `\bar`, (f) change `[0.5mm]` to `\addlinespace` (or, at least, something less minuscule), (g) change `\multicolumn{7}{l}` to `\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}`, and (h) delete the subsequent `\small` directive.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages} % inclusion of external multi-page PDF documents
\usepackage{tabularx} % Tabulars with adjustable-width columns
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y||Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
        \hline
\textbf{Key figures} 
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Toluene}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Nicotinamide}}  
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Adenine}}\\
        \hline
        \hline
\textbf{Retention time} 
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Computed Descriptors}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I would write your table as follows (considering added information in edited question):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx} 
\renewcommand\thead{\small\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\small\bfseries\hsize=1.24\hsize}Y
                                               *{6}{>{\hsize=0.96\hsize}Y} @{}}
        \toprule
Key figures
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Toluene}}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Nicotinamide}}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Adenine}}                 \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-7}
Retention time
        & 1st run (28.09.2020) & 2nd run (01.10.2020) & 1st run (28.09.2020) & 2nd run (01.10.2020) & 1st run (28.09.2020) & 2nd run (01.10.2020) \\
 %    & \mcc{1}   & \mcc{2}   & \mcc{3}   & \mcc{4}   & \mcc{5}   & \mcc{6}   \\
    \midrule
Peak area
    & text      & text text & text text & text text & text text & text text \\
Theoretical plates (USP)
    & text      & text text & text text & text text & text text & text text \\
Asymmetry
    & text      & text text & text text & text text & text text & text text \\
Resolution
    & text      & text text & text text & text text & text text & text text \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Computed Descriptors}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you do it in the vertical way? (see my edited code box Key figures)

Comment: thank you very much! It looks amazing.

Comment: @Elia, sorry, I do not understand what is "veritcal way". So I add an example, how I would write your table.

Comment: I think the OP may be thinking of the effect that's achieve by running `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}`.

Comment: @Mico, yes, it shouldbe. I will add this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I sugest the following variant, similar to [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565194/134144),  in which I placed the repeated dates in a multicolumn below the table. Depending on the actual contents of the cells, this could help save some space and could avoid linebreaks in the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Computed Descriptors}
\label{key}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xcccccc}
        \toprule
        Key figures 
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Toluene} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Nicotinamide} 
              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Adenine}\\
        \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
          & 1st run  & 2nd run  & 1st run  & 2nd run  & 1st run  & 2nd run  \\
        \midrule
        Retention time & 1&2&3&4&5&5\\
        Peak area  \\ 
        Theoretical plates (USP)  \\
        Assymetry \\
        Resolution \\
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\small 1st run: 28.09.2020, 2nd run: 01.10.2020}
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```